Getting timestamp of USB HID endpoint message
How to programmatically get a system timestamp when a USB HID message was received?
My understanding is that the USB controller should raise an interrupt flag and when the kernel processes the interrupt there should be an accessible system time. But I don't see this option in any of the USB tutorials.

Assuming you're using a modern Unix&Linux system, sudo journalctl --since="-3 minutes" --output=short-precise shortly after your event, you can see the system logs, with timestamp in microseconds

Thanks but I need to do it programmatically, ideally when I read in the information.

@FourierFlux then ask that in your question ... I took the liberty of adding a question to your post ... you'll see it when it is accepted
